# Same version of clang++ disagrees on validity of direct vector initialization between Mint and Debian, OSX

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11, clang++

I seem to have written some code that works as intended on OSX (Sierra) and Debian (stable), with various versions of clang++, but doesn't want to compile on Mint (Cinnamon) with the very same versions of clang++.

To the best of my knowledge, this snippet of code is valid C++14 (and was condensed from a larger bit of code I'm working on):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using frobs = std::map<int, int>;

struct sampleData {
  frobs in;
  int out;
};

int main(void) {
  std::vector<sampleData> tests{
      {{}, 0},
      {{{1, 2}}, 3},
  };

  for (const auto &tt : tests) {
    for (const auto &t : tt.in) {
      std::cout << t.first << "\n";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And compiling this on Debian with clang++ 3.5 like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ initialiser.cpp -o initialiser
```

... works and does not complain. However, on Mint Cinnamon with the same clang++ version:

```
clang++-3.5 -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ initialiser.cpp -o initialiser
```

Complains thusly:

```
    initialiser.cpp:14:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<sampleData>'
  std::vector<sampleData> tests{
```

See: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24494631/ for the full error.

I'm quite confused, especially since this seems to work fine on OSX with the clang++ bundled by Xcode as well. I've also installed libc++1 and libc++-dev on both Mint and Debian, and the problem persists if I update to newer versions of clang++ on Mint, while working correctly on Debian.

Note that in this case the weird part is that the same version of clang++ disagree, and I don't care if this compiles and works with G++ (although it does, on all the systems involved, if I use -std=c++11 and omit -stdlib=libc++ which doesn't seem supported by G++).

So, I suppose the questions are:

- is this bit of code legal in the first place?
- is this an issue with Mint in some way?
- how do I get this to work on Mint? Do I need to install additional packages or modify the code?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Whether the code is legal and if I need to install any packages/make changes to the code to get this to work? Clarified in the OP.

Comment: The code is legal, so yes, this is a bug in Mint's package.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - thanks, at least that's one place to start looking then :).

Comment: @Magnus Maybe a different version of the standard library?

Comment: Good catch, @Yakk! Looks like libc++ version is the only difference between the systems that work and the ones that don't. Shame, that, it seems that one would have to fall back to g++ on Mint and Ubuntu 14.04 for C++14 :/.